# Setting Cursor for App Engine Datastore using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cursor, google-cloud-datastore

What should the `startCursor` be set to if I want to query results from my first element to 10th element?

I understand that `startCursor` should be a Cursor object, but what value should I set it to?

My entity ID's are primitive integers starting from 1.

Please comment if any further information is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a cursor on a query when you have it. Otherwise, you simply don't set it - this will query from the very beginning.

For example:

```
Query q = new Query("Person");
QueryResultList<Entity> results;
Cursor cursor = null;
FetchOptions queryOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(500);

do {
    if (cursor != null) {
        queryOptions.startCursor(cursor);
    }
    results = datastore.prepare(q).asQueryResultList(queryOptions);

    for (Entity entity : results) {
        // do something
    }
    cursor = results.getCursor();

} while (results.size() == 500);
```

Comment: Fine but what if I need to start with some random id say x=51 and fetch 500 results i.e till 551? The value of x depends on some other function.

Comment: Then you use `FetchOptions.Builder.withOffset(50)`, but you will be billed for the first 50 entities anyway. A better solution, if you know the id of your 50th entity, is to create its key and run a query where a reserved key property is greater than this key. Obviously, this works if no other filters are applied.

Comment: I can't do that because I have a requirement to sort before fetching the results. Here is my exact problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575440/random-querying-for-google-app-engine-datastore-entities-using-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575440/random-querying-for-google-app-engine-datastore-entities-using-java)

Comment: Is there some way to iterate the PreparedQuery object the way we can iterate an array? Like going to some point 51 from the top and fetching 10 results from that point. I can't use the id because it is a query is sorted now.

Comment: You can prepare a query as a list, and do all the same operations like with any other list, e.g. `results.get(50)`.

Comment: My problem is solved now. Not using cursor anymore, just using offset and limit to fetch the required limits.